# Windows 7 search does not indexing just mpg, mpeg & ts files properties

Tags: search

these extensions properties are appearing correctly in windows explorer at details view mode "frame height/width & length columns" but actually the same columns appear empty in search results!!!

this isnt a windows update or some program responsible for this behavior because i reinstalled windows 7 sp1 and once desktop appeared i started to index the locations but the same issue appeared its some kind of issue in search index itself because when i disable the index and try to search again the results appear like as if i am browsing the normal locations with full columns details, btw this issue isnt in windows 10 it seems fixed by luck while microsoft rebuilding the whole search function or something.

i believe that the solution is in registry editor but i dont know where is it exactly i searched a lot until i found under this key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT* something close to what am looking for but i think this is just a global i just dont know its kind of a maze..

Comment: Have you considered an alternative program for Windows Search, like VoidTools Everything?  Windows Search has sucked for as long as I can remember.

Comment: yes of course i searched a lot but am sorry to say nothing compared with the function built in windows just because the columns & that what couldnt find in any tools. here is another closer key with reasonable values HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\opensearchresult